# Embed one image of a SVG sprite in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, svg, css-sprites

I have an automatically generated SVG spritemap (grunt-svg-sprite) which looks like this [file](https://cdn.mediacru.sh/ahw4Jhv0r6GG.svg):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="116" height="69" viewBox="0 0 116 69">
    <svg width="116" height="25" viewBox="0 0 116 25" id="block1" y="0">
        <path fill="#fff" stroke="#FF51D4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0 0h116v25H0z"/>
        <path fill="#D5FF54" stroke="#FF51D4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0 0h116v25H0z"/>
    </svg>
    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="block2" y="25">
        <path fill="#FF001A" d="M.5.5h19v19H.5z"/>
        <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M19 1v18H1V1h18m1-1H0v20h20V0z"/>
    </svg>
    <svg width="27" height="24" viewBox="0 0 27 24" id="block3" y="45">
        <path d="M.5.5h26v23H.5z"/>
        <path fill="#6BFF4E" d="M26 1v22H1V1h25m1-1H0v24h27V0z"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

This SVG consists of three "images" which have the IDs "block1", "block2" and "block3".

I want to display only "block1" on my web page, so that the dimensions of this image should be scalable. I want to set the width to `10rem` and the height should be automatically adjusted. I did it this way:

```
<img src="https://cdn.mediacru.sh/ahw4Jhv0r6GG.svg#block1" style="width:10rem;"/>
```

And here I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eg3dq70g/%20JSFiddle). The problem is, that the web browser displays all three blocks instead of only "block1". How can I do this with an `<img>`? I have to support the latest versions of web browsers and only IE11, previous versions would be great, but is not a must.

(I can not use the `object` HTML tag, because I am limited in my IE11 support - I can not see the objects on this [page](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-sprites/sprite.html), I see the images of "iframe", "img" and "CSS background" but "object": three times: "Active content removed").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to add some CSS directly to your SVG file:

```
<style><![CDATA[ svg svg { display: none; } svg svg:target { display: inline; }]]></style>
```

This simple CSS prevents all the blocks from display and shows only the one you're targeting to.

[Here](http://goscicki.eu/goscicki.eu/files/jsfiddle/4tze05u4/test.svg) is your SVG file with added CSS and [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/4tze05u4/1/).

While you use Grunt you can automatize it using e.g. grunt-string-replace task (running it on SVG file after processing with grunt-svg-sprite). The task should look more or less like this:

```
'string-replace': {
dist: {
    files: {
        './src/preprocessedSVG.svg': './build/sprite.svg'
    },
    options: {
        replacements: [{
            pattern: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="116" height="69" viewBox="0 0 116 69">',
            replacement: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="116" height="69" viewBox="0 0 116 69"><style><![CDATA[ svg svg { display: none; } svg svg:target { display: inline; }]]></style>'
        }]
    }
}
```

You can add some variables or RegExps to pattern to make it more robust and bulletproof.

--

**The other solution** is to switch to inline SVG nicely described by Chris Coyer (http:// css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/). There is also Grunt task for that - [grunt-svgstore] (https:// github.com/FWeinb/grunt-svgstore).

P.S. You need to copy those links and remove space after "https://" cause I am new to StackOverflow and can not post more than 2 links...

Comment: The first solution, I have a problem with. You see in your JSFiddle the gap between the block1 image and the headline "#block2:"? If you select the image, you see that there is white space at the bottom of the image. How can I remove that? / Other solution: What is the benefit? I have to include the full SVG, so I do not have any caching mechanism, so the user has to load on every page reload the full svg file? / I think otherwise I have to switch to the ``background`` solution or what do you think?

Comment: White padding is caused by viewBox attribute set to SVG. I don't have the solution **yet**. Inline SVG should eliminate this problem because you can set viewBox while you use some part of SVG, like this: `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><use xlink:href="sprite.svg#block1"></use></svg>`. Advantage of inline SVG is that you don't have any additional HTTP request to download the file. When you link to file with #target each time you use different target whole file would be downloaded because browser consider `sprite.svg#block1` and `sprite.svg#block2` as different files.

Comment: SVG with #target as background wouldn't work in Chrome due to some security(?) issues - [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128055#c6)

Comment: And how can I do this with the external one, so that I can scale the image? This is also my problem with ``background-image``. I have a background-image with fixed Pixel coordinates and it seems to be impossible to scale this image.

Comment: In new webkit versions it works with ``:target``! So it would be great to get this solution without the space in your JSFiddle.

Comment: If your SVG shapes have different sizes then there's still a problem with viewBox. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/4tze05u4/2/) is the demo of your sprite used as inline SVG. The only change to the file is added ID for outer SVG (for easy CSS styling) and removed y attributes from inner SVGs. This solution is the most efficient. Targeted SVG is cacheable but browser downloads whole file for each target - [see](http://goo.gl/TmqWWK). To cache inline SVG you can use Local Storage.

Comment: Inline SVG is not an option in my case. I could do it with ``background-image`` and convert the svg to base64 and put it ins one CSS file. So I do not have a SVG sprite, but it seems to be impossible to make your first JSFiddle without the gaps.

Comment: I tried to fix that but it seems that `viewBox` can only be set to outer SVG. It means that if your shapes have different sizes it's impossible to remove the padding. The only solution I know is to use `<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><use xlink:href"#block1"></use></svg>` but it doesn't work with external SVG in any IE. So I hit on the idea to load SVG with AJAX from external source and prepend it to body - [DEMO](http://goscicki.eu/goscicki.eu/files/jsfiddle/4tze05u4/test3.html) using jQuery

Comment: ``<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><use xlink:href"#block1"></use></svg>``was a good hint, I solved it in this way with an external SVG file! And for IE, there is a small library: https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody So now I also do not have to include ``viewBox="0 0 20 20``. Thanks for your help!